# Double arrow in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw two arrows between nodes as follows:

```
A ------> B
  <--/---
```

The arrows should be parallel, in opposite directions but not on top of each other. (I can bend the arrows but that's not what I'm after.)

What's the cleanest way to do this in TikZ? And can I have just one of the arrows "struck out" as in the example?

Comment: For the "strike out", take a look at the answers to the question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/86

Answer (score 16):

Here is an idea that might answer both your questions. It uses `yshift` to move the start and end points of the two paths up/down by `5pt`. The result could be further improved by shifting the start/end points along the x axis in order for the paths to really be in contact with the nodes' circles.

A custom TikZ style is used to add a strike-through marking at the middle of the second path. This could be parameterized further to allow moving the marking to any position on the path etc.

I cannot tell whether this is the most elegant solution though.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
  strike through/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {
        \draw[-] (-5pt,-5pt) -- (5pt, 5pt);
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,circle] (foo) at (0,0) { foo };
  \node[draw,circle] (bar) at (4,0) { bar };

  \draw[>=latex,->]                ([yshift= 5pt] foo.east) -- ([yshift= 5pt] bar.west);
  \draw[>=latex,<-,strike through] ([yshift=-5pt] foo.east) -- ([yshift=-5pt] bar.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Note that you can apply simple shifts on coordinates by using the `yshift`, `xshift` or `shift` options *on the coordinate*: `([yshift=2pt]foo.east)` instead of `($ (foo.east) + (0, 2pt) $)`. This is often not known. It does not require the `calc` library.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that syntax. I tried yshift in the arguments to `\draw` as well as after `--` (also tried `edge` instead of `--`) but neither of them worked. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jannis: If you operate on named coordinates instead of direct ones, you further need `transform canvas`.

Comment: @Andrey: Ah, alright.

Comment: @Andrey: Could you elaborate on this. I don't see why `transform canvas` is required here.

Comment: @Jannis: Your are still missing the diagonal "not" line trough the lower arrow.

Comment: @Martin: I can't find a note on this in the TikZ manual, but can link two [related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-do-i-draw-parallel-arrows-in-commutative-diagrams-with-tikz/7166#7166) [answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15395/shifting-a-path-horizontally-between-nodes/15397#15397) and also confirm this from my own experience.

Comment: @Andrey: It seems to be an issue if you use the node name without an anchor, because then the *border anchor* is taken which depends on the position of the target coordinate. That's basically the difference between `(A)` and `(A.center)`. It seems to work without `transform canvas` if you use an anchor like `(A.west)`.

Comment: @Martin: Oh, that's nice to know!

Comment: I have updated my answer to also include a solution for the diagonal strike-through line.

Comment: @Jannis: if both circles have equal size you can use something like (foo.30)--(bar.150) and the arrows will start and finish at node border.

Comment: @Ignasi: Neat. Another one I didn't know yet. :)

Answer (score 7):

As I think the Ti*k*Z answer here is a bit outdated I'll provide a solution that is more automated using `pic`s and with no need for loading any libraries.

The `strike through` can be drawn as a simple `\draw[-] (-135:0.5) -- (45:0.5);` with a `/.pic` and be called upon within the drawing by `\pic[options]{strike through}` or mid path by `pic[options]{strike trhough}` (the `-` option is because `pic`s inherit the path options, so that overwrites any possible arrow tips):

```
\tikzset{strike through/.pic={\draw[-] (-135:.5) -- (45:.5);}}
\draw[->] (foo) -- pic{strike through} (bar);
```

[image]

For the double arrows, I'm not so fond of shifting because sometimes the shifting values can be tricky. Using bent `edge`s one can achieve a very good result with somewhat little code:

```
\draw[->] (foo) edge[bend right,draw=none] coordinate[at start](foo-b) coordinate[at end](bar-b) (bar)
            edge[bend left,draw=none] coordinate[at start](foo-t) coordinate[at end](bar-t) (bar)
            (foo-t) -- (bar-t);
\draw[->] (bar-b) -- (foo-b);
```

[image]

Well maybe not *so* little... But that's very powerful, as no matter where `foo` and `bar` are placed the arrows will be perfectly separated! Also how much the arrows are separated can be controlled by the `bend angle` key. So, let's get down to business: with that idea in mind, is possible to make a style and/or a `pic` to draw everything leaving our drawing area as clean as possible and the drawing with as much flexibility as Ti*k*Z can offer!

We first create a style `double arrows={#1-#2}` that insert the edges and place coordinates like `(#1-t)` and `(#1-b)` for the `t`op and `b`ottom part of node `#1` and the same for node `#2`. Later on we can use this style to create the coordinates so we draw the path manually (that's useful for placing `pic`s and `node`s mid path).

```
\tikzset{double arrows/.style args={#1-#2}{%
           insert path={(#1) edge[bend right,draw=none] coordinate[at start](#1-b) coordinate[at end](#2-b) (#2)
                             edge[bend left,draw=none] coordinate[at start](#1-t) coordinate[at end](#2-t) (#2)
 }}}
\draw[double arrows={foo-bar},->] (foo-t) -- node[above]{$F(x)$} (bar-t);
\draw[->] (bar-b) -- pic{strike through} (foo-b);
```

Finally, we can make everything very automatic with a `\pic[options]{double arrows={foo-bar}}`. In order to make everything more tikz-like some styles were created, a `every double arrows` that's loaded by the `double arrows` pic, if modified all double arrows pics are modified along with it. Also the `bend angle` can be given to an specific `pic` by the `double arrows split` style (default is 10). Furthermore, a `shorten` key was also introduced so that the arrows do not touch the nodes (default is 2mm). A complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{strike through/.pic={\draw (-135:.5) -- (45:.5);},
        shorten/.style={shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
        every double arrows/.style={-latex, shorten=2mm},
        double arrows split/.style={bend angle=#1},
        double arrows split/.default={10},
        double arrows/.style args={#1-#2}{%
                        insert path={(#1) edge[bend right,draw=none] coordinate[at start](#1-b) coordinate[at end](#2-b) (#2)%
                                          edge[bend left,draw=none] coordinate[at start](#1-t) coordinate[at end](#2-t) (#2)
                                    }
        },
        pics/double arrows/.style args={#1-#2}{%
                        code={%
                              \begin{scope}[double arrows split]
                              \draw[double arrows={#1-#2}, every double arrows] (#1-t) -- (#2-t);%
                              \draw[every double arrows] (#2-b) -- (#1-b);%
                              \end{scope}
                              }
        }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, circle}]
  \node (foo) at (0,0) {foo};
  \node[right=3cm of foo] (bar) {bar};
  \node[below right=1cm and 2cm of foo] (fow) {fow};
  \node[above right=1cm and 1cm of foo] (bow) {bow};

  \begin{scope}[bend angle=20]
    \draw[double arrows={foo-bar}, shorten=4pt, -latex] (foo-t) -- node[above, draw=none, rectangle]{$F(x)$} (bar-t);
    \draw[-latex, shorten=4pt] (bar-b) -- pic[-,red,thick]{strike through} (foo-b);
  \end{scope}

  \pic{double arrows={foo-bow}};
  \pic[every double arrows/.style={->, shorten=0mm}]{double arrows={foo-fow}};
  \pic[red]{double arrows={bar-bow}};
  \pic{double arrows={fow-bar}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With PSTricks. Unfortunately, no option to change the radius of `\circlenode` to be uniform.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{arrows=->,arrowinset=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,2)
    \rput(1,1){\circlenode{Left}{left}}
    \rput(4,1){\circlenode{Right}{right}}
    \ncline[offset=5pt]{Left}{Right}
    \ncline[offset=5pt]{Right}{Left}
    \ncput{\psline[arrows=-](5pt;45)(5pt;-135)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```