# Placing edges side by side?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have **two nodes** which should be connected by edges, one going from **A to B** and one from **B to A**. The problem is, that **they do overlap** but I want to show them as **separate arrows** - so one might shift slightly to the right the other slightly to the left. How might achieve this?

(There seems to be a solution in there [TikZ parallel Edges between Nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/tikz-parallel-edges-between-nodes) but the examples are too complex, so I cannot separate the automation stuff from the placing edges side by side stuff.)

**minimal example:**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[->]
    \node (1) {A};
    \node (2) [below of=1] {B};
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [left] {edge1} (2)
    (2) edge node [right] {edge2} (1)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo has answered already, just adding that there have been other similar questions before, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18078/double-arrow-in-tikz and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35257/how-do-you-get-two-lines-between-nodes-that-have-paths-to-each-other-instead-of

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can introduce some shifting; the code below shows two possibilities; the first one, using `xshift`, and the second one, using the `<name>.<angle>` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[->]
    \node (1) {A};
    \node (2) [below of=1] {B};
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    ([xshift=-2pt]1.south) edge node [left] {edge1} ([xshift=-2pt]1.south|-2.north)
    ([xshift=2pt]2.north) edge node [right] {edge2} ([xshift=2pt]2.north|-1.south)
    ;
 \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \node (1) {A};
    \node (2) [below of=1] {B};
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1.255) edge node [left] {edge1} (1.255|-2.north)
    (2.75) edge node [right] {edge2} (2.75|-1.south)
    ;
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]