# Markov State Model in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am quite lost as I am very new to latex. Could anyone lend me a hand to draw something that looks like this please?[image]

In advance I appreciate your help guys....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For basic learning see either [the manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) or [A very minimal introduction to Ti*k*Z](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). For examples on Ti*k*Z drawings see http://www.texample.net/tikz/ . For the double arrows see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18078/double-arrow-in-tikz/339089). I'm sure you can kick start your drawing from any of those links. `:)`

Comment: Maybe `tikz-cd`, even, or a `matrix` (Ti*k*Z has a `matrix` library, for example) ....

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  >=latex,arrow style=tikz,
  row sep/custom/.initial=6em,column sep/custom/.initial=6em,
  row sep=custom,column sep=custom,
  every arrow/.append style={shift left},
  /tikz/annot/.style={draw,rounded corners,inner sep=.3ex,minimum size=1.5em},
  execute at end picture={
    \draw[dashed,<-] (k+1.south) to[out=180,in=-80] +(-.7,+.5) node[above] {$C_i$};
    \draw[dashed,<-] (k-1.north) to[out=  0,in=100] +(+.7,-.5) node[below] {$3N_i$};
    \draw[dashed,<-] (k-3.south) to[out=180,in=-80] +(-.7,+.5) node[above] {$C_e$};
    \draw[dashed,<-] (k+3.north) to[out=  0,in=100] +(+.7,-.5) node[below] {$3N_e$};
  }
  ]
  |[label={[annot]above left:X_1}]|
  E_i(N_i)_3 \ar[r,"k_1"{name=k+1}] \ar[d,"k_{-4}"] &
  |[label={[annot]above right:X_2},label={right:\mbox{inside}}]|
  E_i(C_i)   \ar[l,"k_{-1}"{name=k-1}] \ar[d,"k_2"] \\
  |[label={[annot]below left:Y_1}]|
  E_e(N_e)_3 \ar[r,"k_{-3}"{name=k-3}] \ar[u,"k_4"] &
  |[label={[annot]below right:Y_2},label={right:\mbox{outside}}]|
  E_e(C_e)   \ar[l,"k_3"{name=k+3}] \ar[u,"k_{-2}"] \\  
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]