# How can I draw this arrow in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: two arrows] there are two arrows I need to show in my tikz picture, meaning:
a). From A cannot get B;
b). B can be derived from A, but not the other way around.

`\draw[->] (a) -- (b)` can get a normal arrow, but what's the command to get these special arrows?

Comment: you can search for it on this site. There are plenty of them asked before

Comment: also related [Q:51022](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/not-implies-not-leftarrow-description-in-the-middle-of-an-arrow-in-tikz-cd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the strike out in the middle part the link  Guilherme Zanotelli posted ([Double arrow in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18078/double-arrow-in-tikz)) can help, I used the highest voted answer there, by Jannis Pohlmann, for the code below.

To make the "half" arrow tips in your bottom figure, use the `Straight Barb[left]` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    decorations.markings,
    arrows.meta  %% <--
}

\tikzset{
  barbarrow/.style={ % style that just defines the arrow tip
     >={Straight Barb[left,length=5pt,width=5pt]}
  },
  strike through/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {
        \draw[-] (-3pt,-3pt) -- (3pt, 3pt);
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A1) at (0,1) { A };
  \node (B1) at (4,1) { B };

  \draw[-Stealth,strike through]  (A1) -- (B1);


  \node (A) at (0,0) { A };
  \node (B) at (4,0) { B };

  \draw[->,barbarrow]                ([yshift= 2pt] A.east) -- ([yshift= 2pt] B.west);
  \draw[<-,barbarrow,strike through] ([yshift=-2pt] A.east) -- ([yshift=-2pt] B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```